# Remove info part from list page in Dynamics AX

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I can't remove one of info parts which is located in AssetTableListPage, what is wrong?
If I has changed in properties Visible:False, it is still visible.

Comment: Could you tell us which part and what version (2012 or D365) you are using? I can reproduce the issue in AX 2012 R3 with all parts of that form. Have you tried controlling the visibility in code ([How to control the visibility of FactBox on form thru X++](http://ax2012pedia.blogspot.de/2012/12/how-to-control-visibility-of-factbox-on.html))?

Comment: It is Dynamics AX 2012. No I only tried to hide it through properties not x++.

Comment: What info part in AssetTableListPage are you trying to hide?

Comment: AssetAdditionsInfoPart